# Is there a python3 version of win32com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, win32com, nameerror

Is there a python3 version of the win32com module?

I am running python 3.4.4 and I tried installing the win32com module, but it is written in python2 syntax.
So I thought I would sort the syntax out myself, but it proved to be a task I couldn't quite handle.

```
line 2403, in convert_optional_data_files
    RuntimeError, details
NameError: name 'details' is not defined
```

Long story short: is there a python3 win32com?

Comment: Why not try [`py2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html)?

Comment: will that be able to do the whole module folder?

Comment: No idea, never tried it. Just seems like a better option than manually doing it

Comment: well i thought it would just be the setup file that i would have to change, so i thought i could do it, but it turns out it wasnt

Comment: Or, maybe you are looking for this http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/whatsincluded.html or these https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

Comment: thanks, i just downloaded the 3.4 version but i got this  ' File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.'

Comment: Looks like you downloaded the 64 or 32bit version when your computer is running the opposite

Comment: i downloaded this one pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.4.exe and i am running 64bit, just checked system info

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, then. Can't help either, really. I'm on a Mac

Comment: thanks for your help anyway. do you think i should try deleting the 64bit and getting the 32 even though im on 64?

Comment: What about your Python version? Is that x86 or x86-64?

Comment: not too sure but here is my top line Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: That says 32 bit. May want to get a 64 bit version. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: or just get the 32 version of win32com?

Comment: Maybe :) There's only a few options here to try. If something doesn't work, it doesn't take that long to reinstall

Comment: I use `pywin32-219.win-amd64-py3.4.exe` for one of my python projects. I'm running python 3.4.2 ( I would think any 3.4.X version be fine ).

Comment: thanks for your help, i got the 32 version of win32com and it worked thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 forgot to mention yesterday, if you want to stick the sourceforge link you gave as an answer i would be more than happy to accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the Win32 bindings you can find them in either of these two projects.

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/whatsincluded.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220

Just make sure to download the corresponding x86 or x86-64 version for the corresponding version of Python

Comment: pip install pywin32